# Oracle - get day of week

Tags: sql, oracle

It's Tuesday today.

How come when I run this SQL statement, it says it's not Tuesday?

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'Day') = 'Tuesday' THEN 'Its Tuesday'
ELSE 'Its Not Tuesday'  
END AS case_result,
TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'Day') AS day
FROM DUAL
```

Returns:

```
CASE_RESULT DAY
It's Not Tuesday    Tuesday
```

Comment: Its, because of embedded space, use of `FmDay` will do better here.

Comment: When you have doubts about exactly what is being returned by a function, try using Dump() to inspect it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try like this,

```
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN trim(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Day')) = 'Tuesday' THEN 'Its Tuesday'
       ELSE 'Its Not Tuesday'  
       END AS case_result,
       TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Day') AS DAY
FROM  DUAL;
```

OR as ajmalmhd04 suggested, you can try with `FmDay` like,

```
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'FmDay') = 'Tuesday' THEN 'Its Tuesday'
       ELSE 'Its Not Tuesday'  
       END AS case_result,
       TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Day') AS DAY
FROM  DUAL;
```

Comment: @ajmalmhd04, thanks for the suggestion. I've added the same in my answer.

Comment: @shakedown7, Oracle pads the value to the length of the longest day, which is wednesday, which is nine characters. So, when comparing values, you need to either rpad or trim the result.

Comment: @shakedown7 - the [documentation for the FM modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#BABDAEDF) refers to the padding: 'The character elements MONTH, MON, DAY, and DY are padded with trailing blanks to the width of the longest full month name, the longest abbreviated month name, the longest full date name, or the longest abbreviated day name, respectively, among valid names determined by the values of NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE and NLS_CALENDAR parameters'.

Answer (score 2):

The value of to_char(sysdate,'day') is actually 'tuesday  ', with two space after tuesday. Oracle pads the value to the length of the longest day, which is wednesday, which is nine characters.

try

```
RTRIM(to_char(sysdate,'day'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'Day') FROM dual;
```

Says "Wtorek" in my country... maybe you are getting the name of the week in your language, not in english?

You can check what DATE LANGUAGE is set in your database using:

```
SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN rtrim(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'Day')) = 'Tuesday' THEN 'Its Tuesday'
ELSE 'Its Not Tuesday'  
END AS case_result,TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'Day') AS day
FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the more formal numeric position of the day in the week will avoid both unexpected padding and locale problems (as @przemyslaw-kruglej noticed).

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') = '2' THEN 'Its Tuesday'
ELSE 'Its Not Tuesday'
END AS case_result,
TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'Day') AS day
FROM DUAL
```