# SQL statement using AND depending on the day of the week

Tags: sql, oracle

I currently have 2 different sql scripts that I need to run depending on the day of the week.  I'm trying to find a way to combine them into one and have logic to check what day of the week it is and run the appropriate changes based on that.

So the basic structure is:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE foo = 'bar'
AND foo2 = 'bar2'
AND foo3 = 'bar3';
```

The only difference is if it's a Monday, one of the AND cases needs to change.

So the pseudo code I need looks something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE foo = 'bar'
AND foo2 = 'bar2'

if day = 'Monday' then 
AND foo3 = 'bar3'
else 
AND foo3 = 'bar3a';
```

Any ideas? I tried to incorporate a Case Select based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19244563/1763917) but didn't work out for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the correct logic is:

```
WHERE foo = 'bar' AND
      foo2 = 'bar2'
      ( (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Dy') = 'Mon' AND foo3 = 'bar3') ) OR
        (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Dy') <> 'Mon' AND foo3 = 'bar3a')
      )
```

Two important considerations:

- This checks both for Monday and not-Monday.
- This uses date abbreviations rather than the full name.  Oracle pads date names so the result is not `'Monday'` but `'Monday   '` and the spaces can make a difference.
- As Thorstein mentions, you can add a third argument, `'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN'` so the result is in English.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be working perfectly! Also thanks, I completely forgot about the padding of the days in Oracle.

Comment: Good answer. However, one should explicitely specify the language when working with names, so as not to depend on matching session settings: `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')`.

Answer (score 1):

A `case` expression returns a value. It can't be used as mentioned in the question in the `where` clause.

Express your conditions using `and` and `or`.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE foo = 'bar'
AND foo2 = 'bar2'
AND (
     (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Day') = 'Monday' AND foo3 = 'bar3') OR foo3 = 'bar3a'
    )
```

Comment: Thank you vkp for the quick response.  I tried a few examples with this code on a demo employee table and for some reason it always picks the OR side no matter what day of the week I set.  So:

`SELECT * FROM emp
WHERE JOB = 'MANAGER'
AND ((TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Day') = 'Sunday' AND COMM = 3) OR COMM = 7);` will always return managers with commission = 7